How to get Bug cycle time for all projects in one widget in Azure DevOps
There is a Widget in Azure Dashboards that calculate Cycle Time of one Project/Team. As we can query across projects and get the data. Is there a way I can get the Cycle Time of all projects in the Organization?
I am able to use the widget it single project. However I do not see an "all Project" option for the widget to show the data for multiple project in one widget.


Is there a way I can get the Cycle Time of all projects in the Organization?

Currently the default Cycle Time Widget don't support to get the across projects data.
Workaround:
I found the extension Custom Cycle Time Header from extension Marketplace. It can choose the data from the query.

So, we can create a shared query across projects to get the data and use it in the custom Cycle Time Widget.

You should add the required date fields in the query Column options so that it can be chosen in the widget.

